# Exception 'Comparison Method Violates Its General Contract!' when comparing two date properties of an object

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

First of all, I've already looked at the many questions and answers about this exception but most of them are just about comparing simple integers or the same properties.
What I have is an object that has two dates, that when one is null I will use the other one to compare, ex of the class:

```
public class MyClass {
  private LocalDate primaryDate;
  private LocalDate secondaryDate;
  private String Code;
}
```

the comparison method is:

```
 private List<MyClass> sortByDates(final List<MyClass> listOfClass) {
    Comparator<MyClass> comparator = ((Comparator<MyClass>) (first, second) -> {
        if (first.getPrimaryDate() == null || second.getPrimaryDate() == null) {
            return first.getSecondaryDate().compareTo(second.getSecondaryDate());
        }
        return first.getPrimaryDate().compareTo(second.getPrimaryDate());
    }).reversed().thenComparing(MyClass::getCodeAsLong);

    return listOfClass.stream()
        .sorted(comparator)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Obs1: `secondaryDate` is never null but I have to use the `primaryDate` as first option to compare, and `primaryDate` is never less than `secondaryDate`
Obs2: `Code` property is saved as a string but don't have any letter, so it can be converted to long

Comment: Please provide a example of `List<MyClass>` values to reproduce the problem

Comment: This problem occours in a enviroment with more than 2k data in the collection, I could'nt get the specific data that break this comparison, all I have is that some have the primaryDate null, and some dont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem is how your handle null for `primaryDate`.
Check the following example:

| MyClass | primaryDate | secondaryDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | null | 1/1/2021 |
| B | 1/1/2023 | 1/1/2022 |
| C | 1/1/2024 | 1/1/2020 |

By your comparator, *B > A* and *A > C* which imply *B > C*
However when you compare B with C. *B < C*, this violate the "General Contract".

In general, when comparing nullable field, we can make use of [`nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst(java.util.Comparator)) or [`nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)):

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator
                                           .comparing(MyClass::getPrimaryDate))
                                           .thenComparing(MyClass::getSecondaryDate)
                                           .reversed()
                                           .thenComparing(MyClass::getCodeAsLong);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the violation, i didnt saw this scenario, but we expect to B < C since we are using the primaryDate as the field to compare when both arent null. NullsFirst doesnt work, because we dont want nulls first, when there is a null, we have to use the other field to compare

Comment: So how would you order A,B,C for my example? B > A > C, or  A > C > B? Or there is some constraint on primary date and secondary date that my example is impossible?

Comment: primaryDate is never less than secondaryDate, like in the scenario B. When primaryDate is not null, most of the cases they are equal, and some exceptions primaryDate is greater then secondaryDate

Comment: Updated the example base on the constraint "primaryDate is never less than secondaryDate".

Comment: And based on your description, is adding a getter `LocalDate getDate() {return primaryDate!=null?primaryDate : secondaryDate;}` and then compare by `MyClass::getDate` what you want?

Comment: its returning C > B > A